# Save finger print to template file - Digital Persona

Tags: vb.net, fingerprint

I have digital Persona finger print reader, what I am trying to do is to save finger print on capture event in directory and show it in `picturebox`. Below code is working for showing it in `picturebox` but how can I save `DPFP.sample` on capture event in directory with .fpt extension.

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class EnrollmentForm
    Implements DPFP.Capture.EventHandler
    Public Data As AppData
    Public Capturer As DPFP.Capture.Capture = New DPFP.Capture.Capture()
    Private Enroller As DPFP.Processing.Enrollment = New DPFP.Processing.Enrollment()
    Private Sub EnrollmentForm_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ListEvents.Items.Clear()
        System.Windows.Forms.Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
        If (Not Capturer Is Nothing) Then
            Capturer.EventHandler = Me
            Capturer.StartCapture()
        End If
    End Sub
    Sub OnComplete(ByVal Capture As Object, ByVal ReaderSerialNumber As String, ByVal Sample As DPFP.Sample) Implements DPFP.Capture.EventHandler.OnComplete
        ListEvents.Items.Add("The fingerprint sample was captured.")
        PictureBox1.Image = Nothing
        PictureBox1.Image = New Bitmap(ConvertSampleToBitmap(Sample), PictureBox1.Size)
        TextBox1.Text = Val(TextBox1.Text) + 1
        If Not PictureBox1.Image Is Nothing And TextBox1.Text = "4" Then
            MsgBox("Your Finger is Registered, Ready for Verification", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Fingerprint Enrollment")
        End If
    End Sub
    Sub OnFingerGone(ByVal Capture As Object, ByVal ReaderSerialNumber As String) Implements DPFP.Capture.EventHandler.OnFingerGone
        ListEvents.Items.Add("The fingerprint reader was Removed.")
    End Sub
    Sub OnFingerTouch(ByVal Capture As Object, ByVal ReaderSerialNumber As String) Implements DPFP.Capture.EventHandler.OnFingerTouch
        ListEvents.Items.Add("The fingerprint reader was touched.")
    End Sub
    Sub OnReaderConnect(ByVal Capture As Object, ByVal ReaderSerialNumber As String) Implements DPFP.Capture.EventHandler.OnReaderConnect
        ListEvents.Items.Add("The fingerprint reader was connected.")
    End Sub
    Sub OnReaderDisconnect(ByVal Capture As Object, ByVal ReaderSerialNumber As String) Implements DPFP.Capture.EventHandler.OnReaderDisconnect
        ListEvents.Items.Add("The fingerprint reader was Disconnected.")
    End Sub
    Sub OnSampleQuality(ByVal Capture As Object, ByVal ReaderSerialNumber As String, ByVal CaptureFeedback As DPFP.Capture.CaptureFeedback) Implements DPFP.Capture.EventHandler.OnSampleQuality
        ListEvents.Items.Add("The quality of the fingerprint sample is good.")
    End Sub
    '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Protected Function ConvertSampleToBitmap(ByVal Sample As DPFP.Sample) As Bitmap
        Dim convertor As New DPFP.Capture.SampleConversion()  ' Create a sample convertor.
        Dim bitmap As Bitmap = Nothing              ' TODO: the size doesn't matter       
        convertor.ConvertToPicture(Sample, bitmap)        ' TODO: return bitmap as a result
        Return bitmap
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you should save your fingerprint templates as *.fpt extension? You could still save them with a *.bmp to remind you they are in BMP image format or if you still insist on saving them with *.fpt extension, add VB.NET code to rename your BMP image files with *.fpt but that doesnt change them from being BMP image files internally.

Comment: I don't have DB to save and I don't want to  save them as BMP.

Comment: What's *.fpt format ? a template or an image ? if it's template, what's format ? proprietary or ISO ?